# How would you interpret a jagged continually increasing silhouette plot for k-means cluster analysis?

Tags: data-visualization, k-means

I am running a k-means cluster analysis of textual data (k = 750) and the following is the plot of the silhouette score by cluster[image]

I am trying to decide optimal k and I'm wondering how one would interpret this ...

1. I am unsure as to why it is so jagged?
2. because it is continually increasing (aside from the start, where this number of clusters would be uninformative), am I to take it that the optimal k is even more than 750 clusters?